# xml sitemap: insert node based on a term reference value

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I need to create a `sitemap.xml` to search engine submission. I know (and use) xml sitemap, but I need that the node is insert in the sitemap only if a field term reference has a specified value. Is there any `hook_*` that I can use in a custom module ?

Comment: There s an incomplete hook invoke code in that module, alternate is you can insert your links in xmlsitemap table, when Xml Cron in invoked it will pick up this link and add it to sitemap.xml

Comment: Which is the hook ? And where i can found more info about this table ? Thanks.